# Backbone.js - render() doesn't work until I type it in the console

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, backbone.js

I've recently begun taking backbone.js for a test spin.  I've got a little app that is supposed to grab data from the server, turn the data into form fields, and insert them into a form.  Unfortunately, when I go to render() the collection view, nothing happens.  However, after the page loads,  if I type

```
fieldCollectionView.render();
```

into the console, magically my fields render.

Here's my app code.  It's the penultimate line that I am expecting to work, but it doesn't:

```
var FieldModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function(){
        return {
            type: "text",
        }
    },
});


var FieldCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: FieldModel,
    url: "/register/Backbone/includes/JSONgetRegFields.js",
    //parse: function(response){
    //  return response
    //}

});



var FieldView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    className: "field_wrapper",
    id: "field_wrapper1",
    template: _.template( $("#field-template").html() ),
    render: function() {
        var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
        this.$el.html( this.template(attributes) );
        return this;

    }
});


var FieldCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
    },
    addOne: function( fieldModel ) {
        var fieldView = new FieldView({model: fieldModel });
        //console.log(fieldView.render().el )
        this.$el.append( fieldView.render().el );
    },
    render: function(){
        this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
        //console.log(this)
    }
});




var fieldCollection = new FieldCollection();
var fieldCollectionView = new FieldCollectionView({ collection: fieldCollection });
fieldCollection.fetch();
fieldCollectionView.render() 
$("#formTarget").html( $(fieldCollectionView.el) );
```

And here is what my returned json looks like:

```
[     { "label": "First Name", "fid": "FirstName", "fieldClasses" : "required", "labelClasses" : "requiredLabel"}  
    , { "label": "Last Name", "fid": "LastName", "fieldClasses" : "required", "labelClasses" : "requiredLabel"}  
    , { "label": "Email", "fid": "Email", "fieldClasses" : "required email", "labelClasses" : "requiredLabel"}  
    , { "label": "Confirm Email Please", "fid": "ConfEmail", "fieldClasses" : "required email", "labelClasses" : "requiredLabel"}  
    , { "label": "Fax", "fid": "Fax", "fieldClasses" : "number cdsphone", "labelClasses" : ""}  

 ]
```

Also I should note that if I used

```
setTimeout( function() { fieldCollectionView.render() }, 120)
```

My collection view renders as well - But I don't feel like that is a great way to proceed.  Where have I gone wrong here?

Comment: Are you waiting for the document to be ready? http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost certainly rendering your view before the data in the collection has arrived. You need to understand the asynchronous nature of backbone's AJAX calls and controlling code flow via events. You didn't paste your `FieldCollectionView` class, but that needs something like this:

```
var FieldCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);
  }
});
```

Then you can be sure when the data arrives, the view will rerender to show the new data.

Comment: Thank you very much - this works.  I knew that had to be the case but I hadn't come across the solution in any of the tutorials yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is one option open to you, add a listener to your views collection.

```
var FieldCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);
    },
    addOne: function( fieldModel ) {
        var fieldView = new FieldView({model: fieldModel });
        //console.log(fieldView.render().el )
        this.$el.append( fieldView.render().el );
    },
    render: function(){
        this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
        //console.log(this)
    }
});
```